# Completely Uninstall Google Cloud SDK Mac

Tags: gcloud

I cannot seem to find an uninstall script for the gcloud sdk.

I have already removed all the components (except for `core` which you cannot remove) via `gcloud components remove [ID]`

I noticed that there is a folder `google-cloud-sdk` located in my user folder, although this only has install scripts. I imagine there are other files or folders which should also be deleted.

Does anyone know of an uninstall script or all the files/folders to delete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Run `gcloud info`. This will tell you, among other things, the "Installation Root". You can just delete that folder and you're done. You can also use gcloud formatting to print just the installation root with `gcloud info --format='value(installation.sdk_root)'`. This is helpful for automation.

If you want, you can also delete your configuration files. You can usually find them in `~/.config/gcloud` on MacOS and Linux, but a safer approach would be to use `gcloud info --format='value(config.paths.global_config_dir)'` to provide the location.

The only other modifications gcloud makes at install time is to put lines sourcing `completion.bash.inc` and `paths.bash.inc` in your `.bashrc` file (if you directed it to do so) and add the installation directory to PATH. These shouldn't have any negative impact but feel to manually remove them too.

Later Edit: Google has [official uninstall instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) for Cloud SDK now. Be sure to check those instructions in case there are changes in the future.

Answer (score 18):

You should also delete the ~/.config/gcloud folder.

Answer (score 5):

Best to rely on official Google Cloud documentation for that, which is short and clear and may vary in the future.

See [Uninstalling Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to go to the installation directory with

```
gcloud info
```

1. Copy the installation directory from the output and navigate there
2. Navigate up one step to the **Cloud SDK** directory
3. You'll find an **uninstaller.exe** application to uninstall gcloud, run it to proceed